# Change Color of Button on Load C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a program which has in form 1 buttons which need to be clicked on to open form 2 which has additional information about the button clicked in form1. I have successfully programmed this to transfer my information over to form 2 on loading the form2.

However, there are background colors which need to be transferred on load in form 2 based off of what was clicked on in form 1.

Is there a way to tell the form 2 which color the background color of the button should be along with the information which transfers to the labels?

I've been searching everywhere, but haven't found an answer that seems to answer my question appropriately.

Is there a way to do this? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a color property on **Form2**, then when create an instance of **Form2** assign value for color
 example:

**Form2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Color _propertyColor= Color.White;
    public Color PropertyColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _propertyColor = value;
            // you can add code to execute when change the property
        }
    }

    public Form2 ( )
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );
    }

    // TODO: MoreCode
}
```

**then for call:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );
    }

    public void CallForm_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2 ( );
        frm.PropertyColor = Color.Red;
        frm.Show ( );
    }
}
```